# Is it possible to use different @Before @After for each test case in JUnit?

Tags: java, eclipse, unit-testing, junit

I am new to `Java & JUnit` and came across different *Fixtures*. I searched a lot on net but I couldn't get the answer.

Is it possible to use different `@Before @After` for different test case in `JUnit`?
For eg: I have the following TC then is it possible to use different `@Before` for test & different `@Before` for test1

```
 import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

 import org.junit.After;
 import org.junit.AfterClass;
 import org.junit.Before;
 import org.junit.BeforeClass;
 import org.junit.Ignore;
 import org.junit.Test;

 public class testJUnit {

@BeforeClass
public static void setUpBeforeClass() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Before Class");
}

@AfterClass
public static void tearDownAfterClass() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Tear Down After Class");
}

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Setup");
}

@After
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Tear Down");
}

@Test
public void test() {
    int a = 1;
    assertEquals("Testing...", 1, a);
}

@Ignore
@Test
public void test1() {
    int a = 156;
    assertEquals("Testing...", 156, a);
}

}
```

Can anyone guide me?

Comment: Maybe your tests shouldn't be in the same class if they don't share the same initialization/context...

Comment: @LaurentG OK. Thanks! BTW, do you know where does `main` is invoked for JUnit as I can't find in it code. Is it done under the junit package?

Comment: JUnit tests don't have `main`. They are called directly from the development environment -- something like right-clicking a class or package and selecting "run tests", or somewhere in the menu; depends on the specific IDE. The code you provided is enough, it does not need more methods. What do you use: Eclipse, NetBeans, ...?

Comment: @ViliamBúr I am using Eclipse. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want different `Before` and `After`, put each test in its proper public class

> Method that is marked with @Before will be executed before executing
>   every test in the class.

Comment: You can use After/Before methods from a superclass too.
So if you want more classes per After/Before just put them into an (abstract) super class. As the name says the super Before will run before, the super After after the annotated methods of your subclass.

Answer (score 6):

Just write a private method that you call in the test.